# How can I have listener for a DOM element with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I want to monitor a `<div id="please_monitor_me">` whether it is visible or not. If it is not visible, I want to remove the margin (`margin: 0;`).

I want it to have no margin when it is not visible because later it can be shown with a burger button.

https://jsfiddle.net/4tusk977/

When the mobile view active and the burger button is shown and clicked, I want to remove the unnecessary margin on the top and on the bottom of the form.

Comment: do you have access to AngularJS where this div is located? or is it outside AngularJS app?

Comment: Sorry! I haven't put AngularJS yet and currently trying to figure out with JQuery. But the `"#main_menu"` is inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little snippet using AngularJS.
Simply add a CSS property of your element followed by the class `.hg-hide` and override in these rules all the styles you want to change that will be applied only when the element will be hidden:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.isVisible = true;
  $scope.toggleVisibility = function() {
    $scope.isVisible = !$scope.isVisible;
  };
}
```

```css
.my-div.ng-hide {
  margin: 0px;
}

.my-div {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggleVisibility()">
    Toggle visibility
  </button>
    <div class="my-div" ng-show="isVisible">
      MY DIV
    </div>
    <div>
      MY OTHER DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Andrey's approach is right. The full code would be:

```
.navbar-form {
     margin-top: 0; 
     margin-bottom: 0; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-form {
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiabani/zaobtom0/)